# Can I use 'firsts' referring to people and not to goods?

Tags: nouns

From Collins English Dictionary:

**firsts:** 
*saleable goods of the highest quality*.

Anyway, can I use the same term as a plural of the noun *first* and thus refer it to people? I would use it in an expression like:

*Claude-Louis Navier and Augustin-Louis Cauchy, the firsts to introduce the concept of...*

Is it correct?

Comment: You don't need plural in the given sentence though there are two guys there. That said, a little more home work, and you will discover why it's okay to use *first* for people (but no, **not** in the sense stated by you). Look up the word in a good dictionary. Good Luck.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but isn't *first* here a noun given the fact that there is an article in front of it? In my mother tongue the construction would be different, so maybe I am just thinking in my language

Comment: @RGE _first_ would be an adjective, with the noun omitted. It could be expanded to _...the first people to introduce..._

Comment: @OliverMason clear, so I assume it is just the same as in *the rich (people)* or *the Chinese (people)*

Comment: @RGE exactly. Arguably the examples you give are so common that one could see them as nouns. But word classes are only a construct devised to describe language, and have no real a priori existence anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The meaning of *firsts* is not what you want here. It is a quality measure, compare with [*seconds*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/seconds), goods with a manufacturing fault or other feature that diminishes their quality (and value):

**seconds**
plural noun
1. 
goods of inferior quality
*Some of the articles you see are seconds.*
*It's a shop selling discounted lines and seconds.*

It thus cannot be used to refer to people; in your case you'd simply use the adjective *first*: *Claude-Louis Navier and Augustin-Louis Cauchy, the first to introduce the concept of...*